# Запутался в многомерных массивах, хэлп))

Tags: php, foreach, php7, for

Проблема такая, есть многомерный массив, с двумя ключами AUTHORS и BOOKS, в этих ключах еще вложены массивы, ключами для авторов являются их емэйлы чтобы на основе email автора у книги можно было получить автора

Вот собственно говоря код:

```
$result3 = [

 'AUTHORS' => [
    'pasha12316@ya.ru'=>[

        'fio' => 'Pavel Kharchenko',
        'email_author' => 'pasha12316@ya.ru',
        'year_of_birth' => '1990'

    ],

    'alex6@ya.ru'=>[

        'fio' => 'Alex York',
        'email_author' => 'alex6@ya.ru',
        'year_of_birth' => '1991'

    ],

    'antony@ma.ru'=>[

        'fio' => 'Anton Svyaz',
        'email_author' => 'antony@ma.ru',
        'year_of_birth' => '1992'

    ]
],



'BOOKS' => [

    'pasha12316@ya.ru'=>[

        'title' => 'Progressive',
        'email_book' => 'pasha12316@ya.ru'

    ],


    'alex6@ya.ru'=>[

        'title' => 'Interactive',
        'email_book' => 'alex6@ya.ru'


    ],


    'antony@ma.ru'=>[

        'title' => 'Combination',
        'email_book' => 'antony@ma.ru'

      ]
    ]
   ];
```

Итогом всего, я хочу вывести по порядку в цикле информацию про книги и авторов: Существует книга "title", автор ее "fio", родился "year_of_birth"

т.к у меня 3 автора и 3 книги, результат должен расположится на 3х строках

Я вывел всю информацию в двух разных циклах

```
    foreach ($result3['BOOKS'] as $keys =>&$values) {
    foreach ($values as $key=>&$value) {
        print_r($value);
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
       }
   }


  foreach ($result3['AUTHORS'] as $keys =>&$values) {
      foreach ($values as $key=>&$value) {
          print_r($value);
          echo "<br/>";
          echo "<br/>";
      }
  }
```

вроде эффект дало, вывелось все что есть в массиве, но не могу вытащить их для вывода html разметку
Выводить поэлементно, используя просто поиск в виде $array[0][1] и так 10 строк неправильно будет (а если там 500 авторов и 500 книг)
уже долго сижу над этим, прошу помощи ))

Comment: покажите пример того, что Вы хотите получить в результате

Comment: “Книга Progressive, ее написал <Фио автора> <Год Рождения автора> (<email автора>)”

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если я понял правильно, то получайте значения по ключу.

Также можно изменить логику массива, убрать лишний элемент `email_author` и `email_book`. Вместо них будет выступать ключ.

```
// Я уменьшил количество данных для более упрощенного чтения кода.

$results = [
   'AUTHORS' => [
       'pasha12316@ya.ru' => [
           'fio' => 'Pavel Kharchenko',
           'year_of_birth' => '1990'
       ]
   ],
   'BOOKS' => [
       'pasha12316@ya.ru' => [
           'title' => 'Progressive',
       ]
    ]
];
```

Для их вывода будем использовать ключи.

```
// Для начала выведем авторов

foreach ($results['AUTHORS'] as $email => $info) {
    echo "<p><span>$email</span> " . $info['fio'] . $info['year_of_birth'] . "</p>";
}

// Затем книги

foreach ($results['BOOKS'] as $email => $info) { 
    echo "<p><span>$email</span> " . $info['title'] . "</p>";
}
```

---

Можно также структуру данных таким образом, сделать вместо поиска по ключу, простой перебор массива (списка) со вложенным списком книг.

```
$results = [
    [
        'name' => 'Pavel Kharchenko',
        'email' => 'pasha12316@ya.ru',
        'born' => 1990,
        'books' => [
            [
                'title' => 'Progressive',
                'written' => 2012 // Добавил ещё один элемент для примера.
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

А затем перебрать его таким образом

```
foreach ($results as $entry) {
    echo "<p>Author: " . $entry['name'] . "</p>";
    echo "<p>Email: " . $entry['email'] . "</p>";
    echo "<p>Was born in: " . $entry['born'] . "</p>";
    echo "<p>Books:</p>";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($entry['books'] as $book) {
        echo "<li><p>" . $book['title'] . " written in " . $book['written'] . "</p></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

**Обновлено по комментарию**

```
foreach ($results as $author) {
    foreach ($author["books"] as $book) {
        echo "<p>Книга " . $book['title'] . ", её написал " . $author['name'] . " " . $author['born'] . " (" . $author['email'] . ")</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное !!! это то что нужно !!

Comment: используя foreach для парсинга информации мы сначало авторы, потом книги, щас пытаюсь соединить, сделать в одну строчку, привести к виду


“Книга <название книги>, ее написал <Фио автора> <Год Рождения автора> (<email автора>)” неособо выходит

Comment: @ПашаХарченко обновил ответ.

Comment: $results = [
   'AUTHORS' => [
       'pasha12316@ya.ru' => [
           'fio' => 'Pavel Kharchenko',
           'year_of_birth' => '1990'
       ]
   ],
   'BOOKS' => [
       'pasha12316@ya.ru' => [
           'title' => 'Progressive',
       ]
    ]
];


Это самое подходящее решение)) действительно, лучше сделать ключом и исключить поле email
но перебирая 2мя foreach сначало авторов6 потом книги, выводятся как 2 разных массива, соединить которые в одно у меня не выходит(

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($result3['BOOKS'] as $email => $book) {
    echo $book['title'];
    echo "<br/>";
    $result3['AUTHORS'][$email]['fio'];
    echo "<br/>";
    $result3['AUTHORS'][$email]['year_of_birth'];
}
```

Comment: Интересно кто минусит единственный правильный ответ?

Answer (score 0):

Сам массив реализовал немного по другому, но выглядит вроде ничего и работает как надо:

```
<?php
/**
Массив создан.
Ключами для каждого из авторов сделайте их email — чтобы на основе 
email автора у книги можно было получить автора. 
*/
$result3 =
[
    'authors' => 
    [
        'eckharttolle@gmail.com'=>
        [
            'name' => 'Ульрих Леонард Толле',
            'yo' => 1896,
        ],
        'jacklondon@gmail.com'=>
        [
            'name' => 'Джон Гри́ффит Че́йни',
            'yo' => 1947,
        ],
        'stephenrcovey@gmail.com'=>
        [
            'name' => 'Стивен Р. Кови',
            'yo' => 1967,
        ],
    ],
    'books' => 
    [
        1 => 
        [
            'title' => 'Сила момента Сейчас',
            'email' => 'eckharttolle@gmail.com',
        ],

        2 => 
        [
            'title' => 'Морской волк',
            'email' => 'jacklondon@gmail.com',
        ],

        3 => 
        [
            'title' => 'Семь навыков высокоэффективных людей',
            'email' => 'stephenrcovey@gmail.com',
        ],
    ],
];
/* 
• Выведите информацию по всем книгам, в формате:
  “Книга <Название книги>, ее написал <Фио автора> <Год Рождения автора> (<email автора>)”
 */

foreach ($result3['books'] as $book) {
 echo 'Книга: ' . $book['title'] . ', ее написал: ' .
      $result3['authors'][$book['email']]['name'] . ' ' .
      $result3['authors'][$book['email']]['yo'] . ' ' .
      "(" . $book['email'] . ")" . '<br>';
}

/*  Затем перемешайте (Найдите подходящую функцию) книги 
    и снова выведите информацию по книгам
*/
echo'<br>';

shuffle ($result3['books']);
echo '<pre>', var_dump ($result3['books']), '</pre>';

echo '<br>';

foreach ($result3['books'] as $book) {
    echo 'Книга: ' . $book['title'] . ', ее написал: ' .
         $result3['authors'][$book['email']]['name'] . ' ' .
         $result3['authors'][$book['email']]['yo'] . ' ' . 
         "(" . $book['email'] . ")" . '<br>';
   }
```